# How can I sort a nested restheart data column?

Tags: json, mongodb, restheart

I have a table with several columns which I need to be sorted. I'm using RestHeart Api and this is what I am feeding the column with:

```
{
    "type": "text",
    "size": "sm",
    "id": "labelEstado",
    "pathToValue": "estados___[key=='status']",
    "text": "estado",
    "icon": {
        "cancelled": "glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle fx-status-success",
        "ok": "glyphicon glyphicon-ok fx-status-success",
    },
    "filter": true,
    "sort": true
}
```

Something seems to be confusing the sorting process as the request is always passing the id in the GET request instead of "status" that is a "nested field" inside "estado"...

I tried

```
"sort": "status"
```

and

```
"sort": "estados.status"
```

but the GET request isn't filled properly (keeps ending in `&sort_by=labelEstado`) and no filter button over the column shows up.

How can I get the filter option to allow the filter button to show up but filter by "status" value?

Comment: Could you please write down the query-string in your GET request, so that we can understand what you're actually doing? Ref: https://restheart.org/learn/query-documents/#sorting

Comment: This is the query string for the whole data{
    "key": "queryString",
    "value": {
        "page": "((page))",
        "pagesize": "((pagesize))",
        "count": null
    },
    "sort": "creationDte",
    "direction": "DESC"
}
and the query used/tested in postman:
http: //localhost/Data?page=1&pagesize=10&count&sort_by=status